# How to force alert window to pop-up

Tags: javascript

After several time showing alert window the browser ask whether to prevent creating additional dialog.

Is there a way to force JavaScript show alert window even the user has checked the 'Prevent this page from creating additional dialog' ?

Comment: Erm... that would *kind of* defeat the purpose of that checkbox, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think that functionality is controlled by the browser. I doubt it can be overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Thank goodness.

(you could, however, fake it with a modal dialog--possibly [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) would suit your needs)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of that checkbox is to prevent sites from continuously spamming the user with alert boxes, preventing them from accessing anything in their browser anymore, even switching tabs. If it were possible for a site to continue posting new alert messages after the user decided he doesn't want to see it anymore, the whole buisness of "Don't click this link" where you'd end up on an infinite loop of alerts if you did click it, would be made possible again. Nobody wants that.